# Why does register_tm_clones and deregister_tm_clones reference an address past the .bss section? Where is this memory allocated?

Tags: c, memory-management, objdump, readelf

`register_tm_clones` and `deregister_tm_clones` are referencing memory addresses past the end of my RW sections. How is this memory tracked?

**Example:** In the example below `deregister_tm_clones` references memory address `0x601077`, but the last RW section we allocated, `.bss` starts at `0x601069` and has size `0x7`, adding we get `0x601070`. So the reference is clearly past whats been allocated for the `.bss` section and should be in our heap space, but who's managing it.

```
objdump -d main
...
0000000000400540 &lt;deregister_tm_clones&gt;:
  400540:       b8 77 10 60 00          mov    $0x601077,%eax
  400545:       55                      push   %rbp
  400546:       48 2d 70 10 60 00       sub    $0x601070,%rax
  40054c:       48 83 f8 0e             cmp    $0xe,%rax
...

readelf -S main
...
[25] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000601040  00001040
   0000000000000029  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     16
[26] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000601069  00001069
   0000000000000007  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
[27] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00001069
   0000000000000058  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
[28] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000019f2
   000000000000010c  0000000000000000           0     0     1
[29] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  000010c8
   00000000000006c0  0000000000000018          30    47     8
[30] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00001788
   000000000000026a  0000000000000000           0     0     1
```

Note that the references start exactly at the end of the `.bss` section. When I examine the memory allocated using gdb, I see that there is plenty of space, so it works fine, but I don't see how this memory is managed.

```
Start Addr         End Addr          Size        Offset objfile
0x400000           0x401000          0x1000      0x0 /home/nobody/main
0x600000           0x601000          0x1000      0x0 /home/nobody/main
0x601000           0x602000          0x1000      0x1000 /home/nobody/main
0x7ffff7a17000     0x7ffff7bd0000    0x1b9000    0x0 /usr/lib64/libc-2.23.so
```

I can find no other reference to it in any other sections. There is also no space reserved for it in by the segment loaded for .bss:

```
LOAD         0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
             0x0000000000000259 0x0000000000000260  RW     200000
```

Can anyone clarify these functions? Where is the source? I've read all the references on transactional memory, but they cover programming not implementation. I can not find a compiler option to remove this code, except of course `-nostdlibs` which leaves you with nothing.

Are these part of malloc perhaps? Still for code that's not using malloc, threading, or STM, I'm not sure I agree these should be linked into my code.

See also [What functions does gcc add to the linux ELF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966097/what-functions-does-gcc-add-to-the-linux-elf)

**More details:**

```
$ make main
cc -c -o main.o main.c
cc -o main main.o

$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc

$ cc --version
    cc (GCC) 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ cc --verbose
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap
 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto
 --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info
 --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared
 --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib
 --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions
 --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id
 --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array
 --disable-libgcj --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function
 --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.1 20160916 (Red Hat 6.2.1-2) (GCC)
```

Comment: Can you add the specific gcc version you're using? I found a place in binutils tests that referenced `__TMC_END__+7`, which matches the value you're seeing, so I wonder if gcc historically had some nonsense like `__TMC_END__+7` (which might be `(char *)(__TMC_END__+1)-1`) in the file.

Comment: Heres another interesting example that seems indicative of a bug in the linker or gcc:

Comment: Here's another interesting example that seems indicative of a bug in the linker or gcc: Note that the .bss section gets treated special since it requires no space in the file it uses the same file offset as the previous section .data `.data  00000000006050d8  000050d8 0000000000000004 
 .bss   00000000006050e0  000050dc 0000000000000030`,  .dynsym shows `__start_bss` as an address based off the file offset, not the address `86: 00000000006050dc 0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   27 __bss_start`. Data taken from /bin/getconf - is there some way to determine which version of gcc compiled this?

Comment: Also seeing these on a gcc 4.8.5, Red Hat as well. It gets called from _dl_init_internal, and seems implemented in libpthread.

Comment: btpw (and I guess also @Leeor, since you confirm OP's findings) claims that *"In the example below deregister_tm_clones references memory address 0x601077"*, but that's not what the disassembly shows: It only shows *pointer arithmetic*, and no actual memory accesses. Could you please provide the **full** disassembly of the deregister_tm_clones function, so we can verify whether it matches my answer or not?

Answer (score 15):

It is just very silly pointer arithmetic code generated by gcc for `deregister_tm_clones()`. It does not actually access the memory at those addresses.

**Summary**

No accesses are done at those pointers; they just act as address labels, and GCC is being silly about how it compares the two (relocated) addresses.

The two functions are needed as part of [transaction support](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libitm/C_002fC_002b_002b-Language-Constructs-for-TM.html) in C and C++. For further details, see [GNU libitm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libitm/).

**Background**

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus) on x86-64, with GCC versions 4.8.5, 4.9.4, 5.4.1, 6.3.0, and 7.1.0 installed. The `register_tm_clones()` and `deregister_tm_clones()` get compiled in from `/usr/lib/gcc/x86-64/VERSION/crtbegin.o`. For all versions, `register_tm_clones()` is okay (no odd addresses). For versions 4.9.4, 5.4.1, and 6.3.0, the code for `deregister_tm_clones()` is the same, and includes a very odd pointer comparison test. The code for `deregister_tm_clones()` is fixed in 7.1.0, where it is a straightforward address test.

The sources for the two functions are in [libgcc/crtstuff.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/crtstuff.c) in the GCC sources.

On this machine, `objdump -t /usr/lib/gcc/ARCH/VERSION/crtbegin.o` shows `.tm_clone_table`, `__TMC_LIST__`, and `__TMC_END__`, for all GCC versions I mentioned above, so in the GCC sources, both `USE_TM_CLONE_REGISTRY` and `HAVE_GAS_HIDDEN` are defined. Thus, we can describe the two functions in C as

```
typedef void (*func_ptr) (void);

extern void _ITM_registerTMCloneTable(void *, size_t); 
extern void _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable(void *); 

static func_ptr __TMC_LIST__[] = { };
extern func_ptr __TMC_END__[];

void deregister_tm_clones(void)
{
    void (*fn)(void);
    if (__TMC_LIST__ != __TMC_END__) {
        fn = _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable;
        if (fn != NULL)
            fn(__TMC_LIST__);
    }
}

void register_tm_clones(void)
{
    void (*fn)(void);
    size_t size;

    size = (__TMC_END__ - __TMC_LIST__) / 2;

    if (size > 0) {
        fn = _ITM_registerTMCloneTable;
        if (fn != NULL)
            fn(__TMC_LIST__, size);
     }
}
```

Essentially, `__TMC_LIST__` is an array of function pointers, and `size` is the number of function pointer pairs in the array. If the array is not empty, a function called `_ITM_registerTMCloneTable()` or `_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable()`, which are defined in `libitm.a`, [GNU libitm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libitm/index.html). When the `_ITM_registerTMCloneTable`/`_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable` symbols are not defined, the relocation code yields zero as their address.

So, when the array is empty, and/or `_ITM_registerTMCloneTable`/`_ITMderegisterTMCloneTable` symbols are not defined, the code does nothing: only some fancy pointer arithmetic.

Note that the code does not load the pointer values from any memory address. The addresses (of `__TMC_LIST__`, `__TMC_END__`, `_ITM_registerTMCloneTable`, and `_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable`) are supplied by the linker/relocator, as immediate 32-bit literals in the code. (This is why, if you look at the disassembly of the object files, you see only zeros for the addresses.)

**Investigation**

The problematic code for `deregister_tm_clones` occurs at the very beginning:

```
004008c0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
  4008c0: b8 57 bb 6c 00          mov    $0x6cbb57,%eax
  4008c5: 55                      push   %rbp
  4008c6: 48 2d 50 bb 6c 00       sub    $0x6cbb50,%rax
  4008cc: 48 83 f8 0e             cmp    $0xe,%rax
  4008d0: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4008d3: 76 1b                   jbe    4008f0 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
  4008d5: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4008da: 48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
  4008dd: 74 11                   je     4008f0 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
  4008df: 5d                      pop    %rbp
  4008e0: bf 50 bb 6c 00          mov    $0x6cbb50,%edi
  4008e5: ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
  4008e7:        (9-byte NOP)
  4008f0: 5d                      pop    %rbp
  4008f1: c3                      retq   
  4008f2:       (14-byte NOP)
  400900:
```

(This particular example comes from compiling a basic Hello, World! example in C using gcc-6.3.0 on x86-64 statically).

If we look at the section headers (`objdump -h`) for the same binary, we see that addresses `0x6cbb50` to `0x6cbb5f` are actually not mapped to any segment; that

```
24 .data  00001ad0  00000000006ca080  00000000006ca080  000ca080  2**5
25 .bss   00001878  00000000006cbb60  00000000006cbb60  000cbb50  2**5
```

i.e. `.data` covers addresses `0x6ca080` to `0x6cbb4f`, and `.bss` covers 
`0x6cbb60` to `0x6cd3d8`.

It would *seem* like the assembly code is using invalid addresseses!

However, the `0x6cbb50` address is quite valid, because there is a zero-size hidden symbol at that address (`objdump -t`):

```
006cbb50 g     O .data 0000000000000000 .hidden __TMC_END__
```

Because I compiled the binary statically, the `__TMC_END__` symbol is part of the `.data` segment here; normally, it is in `.bss`. In any case, it does not matter, because `__TMC_END__` symbol is of zero size: We can use its address as part of whatever calculations we want, *we just cannot dereference it*, because it contains no data, having zero size.

This leaves the very first relocated address in the `deregister_tm_clones` function, `0x0x6cbb57` in this case.

If we look at what the code actually does with that value, it turns out that for some braindead reason, the compiled binary code is essetially computing

```
long temporary = relocated__TMC_LIST__address + 7;
long difference = temporary - relocated__TMC_END__address;
if (difference <= 14)
    return;
```

Because the comparison function used is a signed comparison, the above behaves exactly the same as

```
long temporary = relocated__TMC_LIST__address;
long difference = temporary - relocated__TMC_END__address;
if (difference <= 7)
    return;
```

In any case, it is obvious that `__TMC_LIST__ == __TMC_END__`, and that the relocated addresses are the same, in both OP's binary, and the binary above.

**Addendum**

I do not know *exactly* why GCC generates

```
if ((__TMC_END__ + 7) - __TMC_LIST <= 14)
```

rather than

```
if (__TMC_END__ <= __TMC_LIST__)
```

but in [GCC bug 77813](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77813) Marc Glisse does mention that it (the former above) is indeed what GCC ends up generating. (The bug itself is not directly related to this, as it is about GCC optimizing the expression to zero, affecting only libitm users, and easily fixed.)

Also, between gcc-6.3.0 and gcc-7.1.0, when the generated code dropped that inanity, the C sources for the functions did not change. What changed is how GCC generates code (in some situations) for such pointer comparisons.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I guess it's not related to my case (where I do see unexplained writes into the BSS section), but I still learned something useful.

Comment: @Leeor: Could you upload a small binary (perhaps a Hello World program) somewhere, so I could examine it? Or even send it to me via email (my address is shown on my home page, linked to from my profile)? You see, I have a bit of a difficulty accepting that your case is different -- your question does not show anything contrary to my answer here --; and I'd like to be able to verify that I am wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, the code is a simple raytracer (smallpt) using OpenMP, but on a certain system and with a certain gcc version, it suddenly slows down due to collisions on a read-only array residing in the BSS section. profiling shows a surge in snoops indicating that somebody is writing to these shared lines and invalidating them from all the cores. I was hoping that this question could explain why (but unfortunately did not read the code carefully enough..). Still, the bounty was well deserved :)

Comment: @Leeor: Ah, now I understand; the problem in your case is not in the `deregister_tm_clones()` function at all, but elsewhere. (And I agree, slowdowns due to cacheline ping-pong are infuriating. I've basically resigned to use anonymous memory maps for read-only data shared by parallel simulator threads, just so I can call `mprotect(map, len, PROT_READ)` to catch any write attempts.)

Comment: The construction `if ((__TMC_END__ + 7) - __TMC_LIST <= 14)` is very typical of attempts to force things to land on an 8-byte boundary.  Without this style, stuff sometimes falls on 4-byte boundaries, or even completely unaligned, depending on the target CPU. The lack of alignment then just snowballs into later issues.

Comment: wow, so deep that you dived in guy. great !